# Data frame column vector manipulation

Tags: regex, r

I have a dataframe mydf:

```
                Content    term
    1 Search Term: abc|    NA
    2 Search Term-xyz      NA
    3 Search Term-pqr|     NA
```

Made a regex:

```
\Search Term[:]?.?([a-zA-Z]+)\
```

to get terms like abc xyz and pqr.

How do I extract these terms in the term column. I tried str_match and gsub, but not getting the correct results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try with `sub`

```
sub(".*(\\s+|-)", "", df1$Content)
#[1] "abc" "xyz" "pqr"
```

Or

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(df1$Content, "\\w+$")
#[1] "abc" "xyz" "pqr"
```

#### Update

If the `|` is also found in the string at the end

```
gsub(".*(\\s+|-)|[^a-z]+$", "", df1$Content)
#[1] "abc" "xyz" "pqr"
```

Or

```
 str_extract(df1$Content, "\\w+(?=(|[|])$)")
 #[1] "abc" "xyz" "pqr"
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun for the quick response. I have to thank everyone who has replied.

Answer (score 1):

Just to demonstrate the `word` function of `stringr`,

```
library(stringr) 
df$term <- gsub('.*-', '', word(df$Content, -1))
gsub('[[:punct:]]', '', df$term)
#[1] "abc" "xyz" "pqr"
```

Comment: It is still not the expected output

Comment: Yes. It's easy to remove the last `|` with one more line of code but I m trying to do it directly. I ll add the second line though

Answer (score 0):

'gsub' will help you

```
content <- c("Search Term: abc|", "Search Term-xyz", "Search Term-pqr|")
term <- c(NA, NA, NA)
test123 <- as.data.frame(cbind(content, term))
test123$term <- as.character(gsub(".*(\\s+|-)|[^a-z]+$", "", test123$content))
test123
            content term
1 Search Term: abc|  abc
2   Search Term-xyz  xyz
3  Search Term-pqr|  pqr
```

Comment: @ akrun, first you have used only sub and str_extract, by the time I was posting with gsub example, you have edited your post with gsub.

Comment: But, your post timing shows 7 min and my edit was 13 mins ago.